# Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:

Tags: linux, centos, java

I have installed OpenJDK as mentored below. But i still keep getting this error. I have set the right PATH in bash_profile.

Can someone help me out of this?

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-     plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project poker-protocol: Compilation failure
 [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
 [ERROR] /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
 [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
 [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
 [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
 [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :poker-protocol
```

In my bash_profile i have this:

```
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre
 export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
 export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: *I have installed OpenJDK as mentored below* Well no, you don't mention how you installed it.

Comment: Yes i have, sudo. Still keep getting the error. m0skito, i have installed openjdk as mentored here java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/

Comment: Is there a `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/lib/tools.jar`?

Comment: No, gliptak. I tried searching for it also, but without luck. "find: `tools.jar': No such file or directory" - what to do ?

Comment: Suppose you have only JRE not a JDK on your PC.

Comment: Sorry, i have figured it out after 3 hours. The problem was the wrong JAVA, it should be updated. Not i works.

Comment: @AndersHedeager What package did you install to update? I'm curious since as far as I know the openjdk only contains the JRE while to get the JDK you should intall the openjdk-devel package.

Answer (score 4):

You have installed the Java runtime, but to develop Java applications you need the JDK, hence you must install the OpenJDK devel package,in your case `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel-1.6.0.0.x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about that but in my case i have set it this way :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_11/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I have done this in `bash.bashrc`

Try adding `export` before providing the variable name. Another thing i discovered even thought am not using openjdk, is that the `tool.jar` is not locate in the `jre` directory but under `jdk` directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the **java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel**   installing the java-1.6.0-openjdk  just installs JRE .